# Can someone explain why multiprocessing does't work?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

This is my code:

```
import MainController
import Screen
import multiprocessing

def Main():
    main = MainController.MainController()
    screen = Screen.ScreenData()
    pJames = multiprocessing.Process(target = main.detect_James)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=screen.screen)
    pJames.start()
    p2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Can someone explain why none of the function become active?

Comment: Maybe `__name__ != '__main__'`...

Comment: No, but thanks for the help. The only thing that I found that did something was wheb i putted () after the targets, but then it only actived 1.

Comment: It's also possible that one (or more) of your calls are blocking

Comment: Block it what way like errors??

Comment: Blocking means the call stops the execution of the program, for example `time.sleep(10)` is blocking for 10 seconds.

Comment: If something is blocking how do I find what is blocking.